# Get table of prices from webpage into a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the following table - [from link](http://www.immopreise.at/Wien/Wohnung/Miete) - into a google sheet.

I tried the following:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.immopreise.at/Wien/Wohnung/Miete","//table[@id='preisTabelle']")
```

Attached you can find an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-aXJULo6BELQQ6136Lps_HUzOwkw5SKaPGxIl5gBDfM/edit?usp=sharing

My problem is I do not get anything back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Approach: Here is how you can do it (Using ImportXml and RegexExtract:**

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.immopreise.at/Wien/Wohnung/Miete",
           "//table[@id='preisTabelle']")
```

The mentioned code produces an empty string, because, the web page has an empty table at that location, shown as below:

```
<table id="preisTabelle"></table>
```

The data is actually located inside a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
            var ImmoOptions = {"mapOptions":{"region":"Wien","karteAnzeigen":true},"TrendChartConf":{"uri":{"district":"/Trend/GetDistricts","chart":"/Trend/GetChart","chart1":"/Trend/GetTrendChart","compare":"/Preisvergleich","chart2":"/Trend/TrendChart","refresh":"/Preisentwicklung","uebersicht":"/?region=Wien\u0026pathInfo=Wohnung%2FMiete"},"firstDirstrict":{"Wien":"Wien-1-Innere-Stadt","Niederoesterreich":"Sankt-Poelten-Stadt","Burgenland":"Eisenstadt-Stadt","Oberoesterreich":"Linz-Stadt","Steiermark":"Graz-Alle-Bezirke","Kaernten":"Klagenfurt-Stadt","Salzburg":"Salzburg-Stadt","Tirol":"Innsbruck-Stadt","Vorarlberg":"Bregenz"},"firstDirstrictId":{"9":231,"3":153,"1":133,"4":177,"6":201,"2":142,"5":195,"7":218,"8":228}},"preisInfos":{"tabelle":{"spalten":[{"name":"≤50m²","spaltenArt":"Waehrung","nachkommaStellen":true,"farbmarkierung":null},{"name":"51-80m²","spaltenArt":"Waehrung","nachkommaStellen":true,"farbmarkierung":null},{"name":"81-129m²","spaltenArt":"Waehrung","nachkommaStellen":true,"farbmarkierung":null},{"name":"\u003e130m²","spaltenArt":"Waehrung","nachkommaStellen":true,"farbmarkierung":null},{"name":"\u003cspan class=\u0027Detailed\u0027\u003e\u0026#216;/m²\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027Compact\u0027\u003e\u0026#216;/m²\u003c/span\u003e","spaltenArt":"Waehrung","nachkommaStellen":true,"farbmarkierung":true},{"name":"\u003cspan class=\u0027Detailed\u0027\u003eTrend\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027Compact\u0027\u003eTd.\u003c/span\u003e","spaltenArt":"Tendenz","nachkommaStellen":false,"farbmarkierung":null}],"zeilen":[{"name":" 1.,  Innere Stadt","zellen":[21.68,19.02,18.43,19.56,19.27,0],"id":231},{"name":" 2.,  Leopoldstadt","zellen":[18.27,15.06,14.28,14.20,14.85,1],"id":232},{"name":" 3.,  Landstraße","zellen":[18.88,17.04,15.42,14.68,16.03,1],"id":233},{"name":" 4.,  Wieden","zellen":[19.37,16.58,16.89,16.35,16.83,1],"id":234},{"name":" 5.,  Margareten","zellen":[15.46,14.11,14.20,14.77,14.39,0],"id":235},{"name":" 6.,  Mariahilf","zellen":[18.23,14.68,15.72,15.32,15.53,1],"id":236},{"name":" 7.,  Neubau","zellen":[16.09,14.89,14.58,14.94,14.95,0],"id":237},{"name":" 8.,  Josefstadt","zellen":[16.77,16.78,14.02,14.93,15.08,0],"id":238},{"name":" 9.,  Alsergrund","zellen":[15.72,14.48,14.53,14.92,14.69,0],"id":239},{"name":"10.,  Favoriten","zellen":[14.14,12.35,11.81,0,12.52,0],"id":240},{"name":"11.,  Simmering","zellen":[13.69,12.34,11.50,13.46,12.38,-1],"id":241},{"name":"12.,  Meidling","zellen":[15.66,14.97,13.28,11.79,14.54,1],"id":242},{"name":"13.,  Hietzing","zellen":[16.71,15.93,14.63,14.05,14.99,0],"id":243},{"name":"14.,  Penzing","zellen":[14.43,13.14,12.72,12.37,13.11,0],"id":244},{"name":"15.,  Rudolfsheim-Fünfhaus","zellen":[13.58,12.90,12.93,11.76,13.07,0],"id":245},{"name":"16.,  Ottakring","zellen":[13.99,12.64,12.64,12.45,12.90,0],"id":246},{"name":"17.,  Hernals","zellen":[14.71,13.06,13.15,13.61,13.50,1],"id":247},{"name":"18.,  Währing","zellen":[14.47,13.96,13.82,15.67,14.37,0],"id":248},{"name":"19.,  Döbling","zellen":[16.21,14.37,15.06,16.44,15.29,0],"id":249},{"name":"20.,  Brigittenau","zellen":[15.68,13.57,12.56,13.30,13.43,0],"id":250},{"name":"21.,  Floridsdorf","zellen":[15.58,13.58,12.38,14.97,13.68,1],"id":251},{"name":"22.,  Donaustadt","zellen":[18.19,15.57,16.85,15.89,16.18,0],"id":252},{"name":"23.,  Liesing","zellen":[14.79,14.09,13.49,15.60,13.92,1],"id":253}],"tabellenTitel":"Wohnungen Miete","titelErsteSpalte":"Bezirk","GesamtAnzahlObjekte":12739},"preisspannen":[{"bis":12},{"bis":14},{"bis":15},{"bis":null}]},"basecharts":null,"CurrentView":{"trendVar":{"CatNum":0,"ImmoArtNum":5,"AltbauNum":2,"AngebotTypeNum":1},"hid":0}} ;
            jQuery(function () {
                InitMap(ImmoOptions.mapOptions); 
            });
</script>
```

The data of most interest is found inside variable ImmoOptions:

```
[
  {
    "name": " 1.,  Innere Stadt",
    "zellen": [21.68, 19.02, 18.43, 19.56, 19.27, 0],
    "id": 231
  },
  {
    "name": " 2.,  Leopoldstadt",
    "zellen": [18.27, 15.06, 14.28, 14.2, 14.85, 1],
    "id": 232
  },
  /* Edited for brevity */
]
```

The following formula can get the script into a cell in spread sheet (let's say we pasted it into cell A[100]) ..

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.immopreise.at/Wien/Wohnung/Miete","//script[2]")
```

Then, the following formula extracts JSON string (value of the ImmoOptions variable) into a cell (let's say we pasted the following into cell A[1]) ..

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A100,"(?s)=(.*)")
```

At this point, we need javascript to parse JSON. This can be done by converting the sheet to a *Google App* (Tools->Script Editor) and doing the coding in javascript.

In the javascript, there will be three steps (The details are not shown here):

```
1. Use IMPORTXML to get the data inside script (in the url/page)
2. Use REGEXEXTRACT to get the value of ImmoOptions as JSON string
3. Parse JSON string to get the data
```

---

**Second Approach: Here is how you can do it using Google App/Script:**

1. Log into google and open [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18nkSuTPmN9pj4dDfZ5hXSKt0jX7aJu7Atu75bQoH4OA/edit#gid=0) in browser.
2. Choose `File->Make a Copy` (may be with a name like S1). This will make a copy of the file in your google drive; and opens it in a new tab.
3. Go to that new window/tab. Choose `Tools->Script Editor`. This will put you into a editor with the script. From the toolbar select the function `doGet` and run the script; it will generate the spreadsheet.

**Here is the script attached with the sheet (for reference, in case the link goes missing):**

```
function doGet() {
  var r1=Math.random()*100000000000;
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.immopreise.at/Wien/Wohnung/Miete?somevariable=" + r1).getContentText();
  var re = /var ImmoOptions = (.*);/i;  
  var jo=JSON.parse(re.exec(html)[1]);  
  var arr=jo["preisInfos"]["tabelle"]["zeilen"];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear(); sheet.appendRow([r1]);
  sheet.appendRow(['Bezirk','Col-1','Col-2','Col-3','Col-4','Col-5','Col-6']);

  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      var item = arr[i]; var row=[item.name];
      row=row.concat(item.zellen); sheet.appendRow(row);

  }  
}
```

**How it works:**

1. Pulls the entire html content of the relevant url.
2. Uses regular expression to extract json data from inside `<script>..</script>`
3. Parses the extracted json data.
4. Gets the relevant array; populates into the spreadsheet.

**Disadvantages:**

1. It is a brittle patch-work script that will break with changes in the `<script>` include (or in any other way regex's break)
2. Doesn't give you nice controls on the UI of table (They could be built, but with more work).
3. Works only if the entire json data is in a single line (Could be modified by removing new lines .. or by using a proper regex).

Comment: Thx for your reply! Any suggestions how to parse the json string into the table format?

Comment: I am trying to get it into a google app. I have the json data. I will post my answer once I am able to get it into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @mrquad, Combined the two answers into one (First one has semi-automation; Second one has full automation using Google Apps Script).